# Compare two list and get the index of same elements

Tags: scala, arraylist

```
val a = List(1,1,1,0,0,2)
val b = List(1,0,3,2)
```

I want to get the List of indices of elements of "List b" which are existing in "List a".
Here output to be List(0,1,3)

I tried this

```
for(x <- a.filter(b.contains(_))) yield a.indexOf(x))
```

Sorry. I missed this. The list size may vary. Edited the Lists

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a result of indices, it's often useful to start with indices.

```
b.indices.filter(a contains b(_))
```

REPL tested.

```
scala> val a = List(1,1,1,0,0,2)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2)

scala> val b = List(1,0,3,2)
b: List[Int] = List(1, 0, 3, 2)

scala> b.indices.filter(a contains b(_))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I corrected the question now.

Comment: This answer is more elegant IMO.

Comment: I get, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException on using this without any modification.

Comment: @sowmiyaksr, as you can see this works for the example data you've given. If it fails for some other input you might update your question with further requirements and examples.

Answer (score 3):

```
val result = (a zip b).zipWithIndex.flatMap {
  case ((aItem, bItem), index) => if(aItem == bItem) Option(index) else None
}
```

`a zip b` will return all elements from a **that have a** matching pair in b.
For example, if a is longer, like in your example, the result would be `List((1,1),(1,0),(1,3),(0,2))` (the list will be b.length long).
Then you need the index also, that's `zipWithIndex`.
Since you only want the indexes, you return an `Option[Int]` and flatten it.

Comment: I would probably use a collect, to avoid the options, but my answer would be similar to this one

Answer (score 3):

You can use indexed `for` for this:

```
for{ i <- 0 to b.length-1
     if (a contains b(i))
   } yield i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> for(x <- b.indices.filter(a contains b(_))) yield x;
res27: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
scala> val a = List(1,1,1,0,0,2)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2)

scala> val b = List(1,0,3,2)
b: List[Int] = List(1, 0, 3, 2)

scala> b.zipWithIndex.filter(x => a.contains(x._1)).map(x => x._2)
res7: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 3)
```

I also want to point out that your original idea of: Finding elements in `b` that are in `a` and then getting indices of those elements would not work, unless all elements in `b` contained in `a` are unique, `indexOf` returns index of the first element. Just heads up.